# Playing Second Sound also replays the first sound?

Tags: jquery, audio

I have the following code:

```
var audiotypes={
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
    "ogg": "audio/ogg",
    "wav": "audio/wav"
}

function ss_soundbits(sound){
    var audio_element = document.createElement('audio')
    if (audio_element.canPlayType){
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            var source_element = document.createElement('source')
            source_element.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                source_element.setAttribute('type', audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
            audio_element.appendChild(source_element)
        }
        audio_element.load()
        audio_element.playclip=function(){
            audio_element.pause()
            audio_element.currentTime=0
            audio_element.play()
        }
        return audio_element
    }
}

var clicksound  = ss_soundbits('Door.ogg', "Door.mp3");
var plopsound  = ss_soundbits('Pet.ogg', "Pet.mp3");
```

and:

```
$("#button1").sequence("click")
.handle(function () { 
$(".overlay").fadeToggle();
clicksound.playclip();
$(".overlay .repeat").click(function() { clicksound.playclip(); });
})
.handleNext("#button2", function () { 
$(".overlay").fadeToggle();
plopsound.playclip();
$(".overlay .repeat").click(function() { plopsound.playclip(); });
})
```

All works well, except when I click the repeat button on #button2 it also plays the sound from button1 (clicksound) - any idea why that would be? I thought it may be because it is the same element - but I also tried adding a class to the repeat button on #button2 and using that to trigger the audio, but same thing happens - open to ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to pause the previous audio clip before playing the next one - dont know why that works, or why it should work!